# javascript mover ficha a la siguiente casilla

Tags: javascript, dom

estoy intentando mover una ficha a la siguiente casilla cuando se pulse el botón, es decir, que se introduzca en la siguiente caja (div), pero no soy capaz de sacarlo. No entiendo que estoy planteando mal, llevo horas atascada ¿alguien me echa una mano? Gracias. Cuando pulso en mover, la consola me informa del siguiente error:

> MoverFicha01.html:82 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute
> 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be
> inserted is not a child of this node.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", iniciar);
function iniciar() {
    document.getElementById("mover").addEventListener("click", mover);
}
function mover() {
    var ficha = document.getElementById("ficha1");
    let nextDiv = ficha.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
    let div = nextDiv.parentNode;
    if (nextDiv) {
        div.insertBefore(nextDiv, ficha);

    }
}
```

```css
    .caja img {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 5px black solid;
        margin: 10px;
    }

    .ficha {
        border: 5px black solid;
        border-radius: 50%;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 30px;
        position: relative;
        bottom: 90px;
        left: 25px;
    }

    #ficha1 {
        animation: rotater 3s;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: red;
        position: relative;
        bottom: 90px;
        left: 38px;
    }

    #cajaGen {
        display: flex;
    }

    @keyframes rotater {
        0% {
            transform: rotate(0) scale(1)
        }

        50% {
            transform: rotate(360deg) scale(2)
        }

        100% {
            transform: rotate(720deg) scale(1)
        }
    }
```

```html
<div id="cajaGen">
    <div class="caja" id="caja1">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/09/13/16/46/pigeon-2746175_960_720.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="ficha" id="ficha1"> 1 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="caja" id="caja2">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/21/59/tree-736877_960_720.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="caja" id="caja4">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/11/08/09/41/deer-5723225_960_720.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
<button id="mover">mover</button>
```

Comment: Encontré el error, ya me funciona!

Comment: Por favor, si tienes una respuesta, es correcto y hasta deseable que la publiques, así otros que lleguen con un error similar aprenderán de ella. Bienvenido a SOes

Comment: Si encontraste el error se agradecería que colocaras que hiciste para solucionarlo, así queda como registro para futuras preguntas.

Comment: Por cierto, no entiendo el voto negativo, la pregunta está bien expuesta y el problema es reproducible

Comment: La solución es sencilla, no debe usar `insertBefore()`, sino insertar en el siguiente div: `nextDiv.appendChild(ficha);`